# How to control an null value within the map function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

it turns out that I'm having a small problem that I find very strange that is not solved with the OR operator (||).

In the following code, you can see that I am sending a

```
 return (
      <div>
        {listShow.map(i => (
          <Link to={`/noticias/detalle/${i.categoria.id/${i.id}`} key={i.id}>
            <h3>{i.titulo}</h3>
            <img
              alt={i.titulo}
              src={process.env.REACT_APP_IMG_BASE + i.imagen_intro}
              width={500}
            />
          </Link>
        ))}
    );
```

However, at some point, **"i.categoria.id"** becomes null and this generates an error that says:

> "TypeError: Can not read property 'id' of null"

Then, I tried this:

```
 return (
      <div>
        {listShow.map(i => (
          <Link to={`/noticias/detalle/${i.categoria.id/${i.id} || 'WithoutCat'`} key={i.id}>
            <h3>{i.titulo}</h3>
            <img
              alt={i.titulo}
              src={process.env.REACT_APP_IMG_BASE + i.imagen_intro}
              width={500}
            />
          </Link>
        ))}
    );
```

I would like to know how to solve this, since it seems strange to me that I take the value when I am putting the operator ||

Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that if `categoria.id` is undefined and you set "WithoutCat" as a fallback, you might end up with dead links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categoria is null and you are trying to access a property of it, check before if it is null, try this instead:

```
<Link to={i.categoria && i.categoria.id ? `/noticias/detalle/${i.categoria.id}/${i.id}` : 'WithoutCat'} key={i.id}>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect!

I will give you the best answer in case someone else has the same problem :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped :)